# Help parse "false as could be"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

> As a musical experience, Eddie Howlloway Live at the Silver Lounge was
> a jolt. Two songs, originals, were vehicles for Eddie to describe,
> simply and sincerely, his enormous lovemaking abilities. These didn't
> interest me except as examples of fine lyrics and vocal delivery.
> Three other originals, however, provoked me in other ways. These not
> only referred to me by name, but described my lifestyle ("dull as a
> mole in his dark hole"), career ("he strikes a pose, this writer of
> indifferent prose"), and way with women ("slick and insincere, don't
> let him call you dear") in outrageous terms. Here then was another
> artist who, like Kelly, was able and willing to insert personal notes
> about **me and girlfriend** into his music, **to make a point**. But
> while Kelly's personal references were true, as I myself had verified,
> Eddie's were **false as could be**. Both artists, however, were true
> song stylists who succeeded in making genuine music. I couldn't
> overlook that, for all my personal involvement in their sounds.
>
> *The dangerous singers* By Michael Fowler ( it's from one of my old magazines on English-learning, but sorry I couldn't find it on the Internet.)

Why **false as could be**, not **as false as they could be**? I've never come across such structure before. Is it an ellipsis?

Please help clarify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*False as could be* does indeed omit the initial *as* in an *as ... as* construction. That is very common in informal registers, and may be acceptable in formal registers. *As could be* is not an ellipsis of *as X could be* but an idiomatic expression employing *be* in the intransitive noncopular sense of “exist, occur”. It thus means approximately “as possible”.  You may also encounter *as can be* and, with a more tentative or dubious sense, *as may be* or *as might be*.

> She petted me and seemed to try hard to make everything as pleasant as could be. —Henry Adams, *Letters*
> Look here, folks, don’t think I’m rough / ‘Cause I’m a good woman and I knows my stuff / That’s why I’m sinful as can be. –Perry Bradford, “Sinful Blues”
> The Commission shall keep itself informed as fully as may be of the circumstances ... —*State of Texas Constitution*
> “That's as may be,” said Kantwise. “I say nothing on that subject at the present moment, either one way or the other.” —Trollope, *Orley Farm*
> My father’s dramatic instinct was as strong as might be. And his power of mimicry was positively fantastic. —May Morris, *Introductions to the Collected Works of William Morris*

You will also encounter an intensive version: *as ADJ as ADJ can/could/may/might be*, where *be* has the same noncopular sense:

> The feeling there was as strong as strong could be that Parnell's leadership is, for the time at least, intolerable. —John Morley to Gladstone.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any solid sources, but "as _ as can be" is an idiom, which basically means "as _ as possible". Here's thesaurus.com with "[easy as can be](http://thesaurus.com/browse/easy+as+can+be)". "as could be" is just a variation on that. If you Google it, there's lots of usage.